# Stored Procedure does not work in scheduled job using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

When I leave the execution of my stored procedure, to call a web service that returns an xml to populate a table, up to my scheduled job, it does not properly work. In the history it says that the step was successful but the records that I know should be in the table are not. Furthermore, if I run the stored procedure manually, it works like a charm. The owner of the scheduled job does have sysadmin permissions, so I don't think it's that.

This is the first time I've tried implementing a scheduled job and I'm not entirely sure what I'm missing. I have also looked at SQL Server Services in Computer Manager, and the logs say SQL Server Agent is stopped but starts whenever the scheduled job is called.

Any ideas?

Edit: I figured out the issue! I needed to put

`SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647;`

to receive the full XML file.

Comment: can you show the message of the log?

Comment: Ok so I now realized that the log was me trying to manually start the SQL Server Agent, and it failing, not the scheduled job.

Comment: Are you using sql server express? That version does not support the agent.

Comment: The DB uses SQL Server Enterprise.